# sequelize fetching associations on find (1.6)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

sequelize 1.6 has the following in the changelog:

> [FEATURE] added association prefetching for find and findAll

The question is HOW?

I have the following models defined:

```
var self = {
    Medium: client.define("Medium", {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
        description: Sequelize.TEXT
    },

    User: client.define("User", {
        firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
        lastName: Sequelize.STRING,
        email: Sequelize.STRING,
        aboutArt: Sequelize.TEXT,
        bio: Sequelize.TEXT,
        password: Sequelize.STRING,
        description: Sequelize.TEXT
    }
};
self.User.hasMany(self.Medium, { as: 'Media' });
self.Medium.hasMany(self.User);

for(var key in self){
    var model = self[key];
    model.sync();
}
```

later when i fetch a user like this:

```
 User.find(id)
    .success(function(record) {
        //record has no media!
    })
```

the User instance does not have a list media. How do i auto fetch associations?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

BTW: Now that Sequelize 1.6.0 is out, the syntax for the eager loading has slightly changed:

```
User.find({ where: {id: id}, include: [Media] }).success(function(user){ 
  console.log(user.media)
})
```

So you'll have to pass the Model instead of the Model's name to the include statement.

Comment: Oh yeah! That is what I am talking about. Thanks @sdepold!

Comment: Is there a way to use the field name instead? That would be very useful, especially considering that you can have separate fields reference the same table.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work: `Item.hasOne(Item, { foreignKey: 'parentAid', as: 'Parent' })`. It says `Error: Item is not associated to Item!`, even though I got: `Item.hasOne(Item, { foreignKey: 'parentAid', as: 'Parent' })`

Answer (score 6):

sdepold actually wrote the code, but I believe the syntax he settled on for include is:

```
User.find({ where: {id: id}, include: ['Media'] }).success(function(user){ 
  console.log(user.media)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is currently only available inside the code, the tests and ... my head :D

```
User.find({ where: {id: id}, include: ['Media'] }).success(function(user){ 
  console.log(user.media)
})
```

The reason for the not yet available documentation iiiiiis the fact, that the release is currently an alpha version.