# Issue with SequelizeJS and relations

Tags: sequelize.js

I'd like to change a value in my model according to a parameter of an associated model...

I don't know how to get the gender of a customer in my appointment model...

```
var Appointment = db.define('Appointment', {
    title: {
        type: Types.STRING,
        validate: {
            len: {
                args: [1, 50],
                msg: 'Vous devez saisir un titre entre 1 et 50 caractères.'
            }
        }
    },
    start: {
        type: Types.DATE
    },
    end: {
        type: Types.DATE
    },
    backgroundColor: {
        type: Types.STRING,
        defaultValue: 'red'
        set: function(value){
            // if Customer.gender === 'M' >> this.backgroundColor = 'red'
            // if Customer.gender === 'F' >> this.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
        }
    }
}, {
    classMethods:{
        associate: function (models) {
            Appointment.belongsTo(models.Customer, {as: 'Customer'});
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use :

```
Appointment.find({ where : {id :1},
                   include  : User })
.success(function(appointment){
    console.log(appointment); // visualize your instance
    appointment.user.gender;
});
```

more infos : https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Model#findAll
look for the option `[options.include]`

Maybe a good answer too : [sequelize fetching associations on find (1.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002873/sequelize-fetching-associations-on-find-1-6)

Comment: doing a query and changing the value on this query will not do the job ?

Comment: will do but is that possible to do this in the model or not?